# Why this jQuery script doesn't work on iphones?

Tags: jquery

I'm in the process of creating wordpress site and I don't know why this script doesn't work on iphones.

I've tested this script on various iphones and each of them had the same issue.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

   function setHeight() {
        windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
        $('.my-class').css('height', windowHeight);
    };
    setHeight();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        setHeight();
    });
}
```

The image I want to be flexible appears with wierd zoom and it's pixelated. Normally the image is scalling vertically and it's cutting horizontally.

Comment: Try to use screen.width instead of window.innerWidth

Comment: @GrzegorzT. Nothing seems to work.. I tried 'screen.width, $.documentHeight() [plugin](https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.documentsize), document.documentElement.clientHeight;'
Added this to the header '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no">'
As far as I can see the wrapper seem to scale correctly. The only issue is that image.

Comment: Can you use https://jsfiddle.net/ to show your code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vesterlay/w01ut72f/19/ @GrzegorzT.

Comment: It works for me https://jsfiddle.net/tomik23/zn2f6hgc/ 
I checked on android (chrome, edge, opera, firefox) and iphone (safari)

Comment: Thank you very much. It appears that the extension of the given image was the problem. I just had to swich jpeg to png and it now works flawlessly.